# Inspired by cloning medium with parchment

Tags: quill

Did somebody tried this examples?

https://quilljs.com/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment

I'm looking for an answer what the

`static formats(node)`

is used for. If it return's

> null|undefined|false

than it seems that nothing is affected.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the format represented by the Blot. For example for a header it might be implemented this way:

```
formats(domNode) {
  if (domNode.tagName === 'H1') return 1;
  if (domNode.tagName === 'H2') return 2;
  if (domNode.tagName === 'H3') return 3;
  return null;
}
```

You can find more details about Blots at https://github.com/quilljs/parchment. Also how Quill implements their formats might be helpful: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/tree/develop/formats.

Comment: Thank you, i thought formats is more like a validation. +1